# How can I restore a completely messed up IMac

Tags: macos, imac

I know this question was asked quite a lot, but I couldn't  find the answer anywhere.

I've got an IMac on which I tried to install Windows 7, it kind of worked but it seems like I formatted the recoveryHD or something. The Windows was really buggy so we tried a Linux Mint since the OS didn't really matter.

Somehow that screwed up the IMac even worse. So the plan was to restore the OSX so we could install bootcamp and Windows again (this time not as a standalone)

But I can't for the love of it recover the OSX. I tried to use the Internet-Recovery which doesn't even show up anymore, I've tried recover using the recovery-HD which is nowhere to be found. I can boot from the OSX-Boot-Disk but it says that the installation can not continue on this machine. 
I made a bootable USB-Stick with OSX on it from which I could boot but not install the OS (Same Problem as with the DVD)

I tried a Time-Machine backup as well which didn't work either.

I'm running out of Ideas, does anybody have any clue on how to make the OSX run again?

Thank you for your help

Comment: When asking Mac questions, please always include information about the exact Mac model identifier (like “iMac12,1” and the exact macOS version(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot the installation disk and get though any initial prompts, run Disk Utility and delete all existing partitions on the drive.

You can do this by selecting the disk and using the “Erase,” option.

Then exit Disk Utility and proceed to install OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Like the user above said, if you can boot to a version of Mac OS using the installation disk then you can use disk utility in the utilities folder in Applications to erase your entire drive and format it to MacOS Extended Journaled. Obviously if you have an installation disk then it's probably an older iMac and possibly the recovery boot section is corrupted. Once the drive is erased you should be able to use the installation disk to reinstall the Mac OS. If the iMac is newer or supports an OS later than 10.6.8 or 10.7.5 or whatever is on that disk then you could have someone else create an install usb for you using their Mac. The process is very simple using the createinstallmedia command. There is an example of the process here: http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/23/create-boot-macos-sierra-installer/